# Java: wait() limits the fps to 64

Tags: java, limit, wait, synchronized, frame-rate

I have this in my code in the main loop(2D game in a window):

```
try{
  synchronized(this){

    wait(3);
  }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

This piece of code causes to FPS to cap at 64 and I don't know why. I don't use any other synchronized blocks. Amusingly, when the web browser is open, the fps is no longer capped. Could anybody tell me how to get rid of that 64 fps limit? I didn't manage to find any other topics with this problem.

EDIT:

- Without the wait(3); - 180fps.
- With the wait(3) and the browser(Opera) open - ~113 fps.
- With wait(3) and without the browser - 64 fps.

How could the browser change fps?

Comment: Who's doing the matching notify() call?

Comment: What FPS do you get when it's not capped?

Comment: The FPS is around 115 when not capped and there's no specified notify() call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the resolution of the parameters of `wait` and `sleep` are in milliseconds you will almost certainly never get exactly the delay you are requesting.

On a Windows system the resolution is approximately 15ms giving 1000/15 = 66fps

Comment: How does running a web browser in the background (Opera) bypasses it then?

Comment: @JanBurak - Your `wait(3)` is normally waiting at least 15ms. I have no idea why Opera helps. Perhaps it increases the tick resolution. I believe Oracle databases can.

Comment: Oh, I see. I measured the time before and after the wait. With the browser open, the difference is from time to time 0(no waiting at all) and other times 15-16 during a single second. Thanks for pointing out that it actually takes 15ms and not the 3ms as I thought(I'm just a beginner, so pretty much every information is important to me). Without the browser the difference is always 15 or 16, so the browser must somehow interfere with wait().

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use any other synchronized blocks, then there is no one to `notify()` your thread. This means you are probably telling your app to sleep for at least 3 milliseconds on each iteration. Additionally, you may lose some more time because of the thread giving up its time quantum as it goes to sleep and the clock resolution is also usually more than 1 ms, depending on OS.

64 FPS means a frame takes slightly above 15 ms. Tell us what your "uncapped" FPS is, calculate to how many ms per frame it translates and see what the difference is. If the difference in frame time wit hand without the losted code is on the order of 3-10 ms (10 ms is probably a reasonable upper limit on clock granularity on a sane system), it is probably only the result of the `wait()`. If without the `wait()` your frames only take 1 ms, there is probably some additional effect.

**EDIT after Jan's comment**: 115 FPS means 8.7 ms per frame. Going from that to 15 because of `wait(3)` seems probable. I'm not sure how running another app in the background may influence it. Perhaps having another task in the background influences the scheduler's behavior. Does the other task bring FPS back to 115 or to some intermediate value?

**EDIT after Jan's second comment**: if it's 180 instead of 115, we have 5.5 ms per frame. This increases the difference, but with the Windows clock being rather coarse (as others pointed out), this is still within the limits of the effect described above.

Comment: Without the wait(3); - 180fps. With the wait(3) and the browser open - 113 fps. With wait(3) and without the browser - 64 fps. What made me confused is that the browser made it go faster.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to get more than 60 fps. A modern Display won't show more than 60fps.

Comment: The problems was that the fps could drop below 60, but actually the fps is more stable and doesn't drop as much as when it's capped. I'm still curious as to what causes the limit?

Comment: The trick is not to drop below 60fps. But there is no need to calculate more frames.